Type narrowing outside switch
I have interfaces like this.
interface subA {
  attr1: number;
}

interface subB {
  attr2: number;
}

interface A {
  type: 'A';
  subList: subA[];
}

interface B {
  type: 'B';
  subList: subB[];
}


type AorB = A | B;
type subAorB<T extends AorB> = T extends A ? subA : subB;

and I have a function like this.
function test(p: AorB) {
  const subList: subAorB<typeof p>[] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    switch (p.type) {
      case 'A': {
        const sub: subAorB<typeof p> = {
          attr1: i,
        };
        subList.push(sub);
        break;
      }

      case 'B': {
        const sub: subAorB<typeof p> = {
          attr2: i,
        };
        subList.push(sub);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  p.subList = subList; // TS2322: Type (subA | subB)[] is not assignable to type subA[] | subB[]
}

I got an error at line p.subList = subList;.  I expect subList is subA[] or subB[], but typescript guesses as (subA | subB)[] because this variable is defined outside switch.
I know I can resolve this error with the code below, but this is very redundant.
function test(p: AorB) {
  switch (p.type) {
    case 'A': {
      const subList: subAorB<typeof p>[] = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        const sub: subAorB<typeof p> = {
          attr1: i,
        };
        subList.push(sub);
      }
      p.subList = subList;
      break;
    }

    case 'B': {
      const subList: subAorB<typeof p>[] = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        const sub: subAorB<typeof p> = {
          attr2: i,
        };
        subList.push(sub);
      }
      p.subList = subList;
      break;
    }
  }
}

How can I let typescript guess subList as subA[] or subB[] even defined outside switch?

The narrowing is called narrowing for a reason, so the types are narrowed only inside conditional statements. You can assign in the switch and still have a compact code, moreover you don't need to do the type check inside the loop, which could be an optimization:
Playground
function test(p: AorB) {
  const length = 10;
  switch (p.type) {
    case 'A': {
      p.subList = Array.from({length}, (_, i) => ({attr1: i}));
      break;
    }
    case 'B': {
      p.subList = Array.from({length}, (_, i) => ({attr2: 1}));
      break;
    }
  }
}

Another option is to use a factory function and if:
Playground
function test(p: AorB) {

  const factory = <T extends AorB['subList'][number]>(cb: (i: number) => T): T[] => 
    Array.from({length: 10}, (_, i) => cb(i));

  if(p.type === 'A') p.subList = factory(i => ({attr1: i}));
  else if(p.type === 'B') p.subList = factory(i => ({attr2: 1}));

}

